# Issue with my ShapeApp in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

I'm getting the error below and these are my classes.

**Shape class:**

```
public abstract class Shape implements Triangle{

 protected static final double DEFAULT_SIZE = (double) 1.0;
 protected static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Unknown";
 private String shapeName;

 public Shape(){
    this.shapeName = DEFAULT_NAME;
 }

 public Shape(String name) {
    setShapeName(name);

 }

 protected void setShapeName(String name) {
 if( name.trim().length() == 0 )
     shapeName = DEFAULT_NAME;
 else
     shapeName = new String ( name );

 }

 public String getShapeName() {
    //name
 return shapeName;

 }



public abstract double getSurfaceArea();

public abstract double getPerimeter();


public String toString{
    return String.format("%s %s\nshape name: %s",getShapeName());
}
}
```

**rectangle class:**

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape implements Triangle {



private double length;
private double heigth;

public Rectangle() {
    super("Rectangle");
    setLength( super.DEFAULT_SIZE );
    setHeight( Shape.DEFAULT_SIZE );

}

public Rectangle(double theLength, double theHeight ){
    super("Rectangle");
    if ( theLength < 0 )
        setLength( Shape.DEFAULT_SIZE );
    else setLength( theLength );

    if ( theHeight < 0)
        setHeight( Shape.DEFAULT_SIZE );
    else setHeight( theHeight );
}



public double getSurfaceArea() {
    return this.length * this.heigth;
}

public double getPeremeter() {
    return 2 * this.length + 2 * this.length;

}

public double getLength(){
    return this.length;
}

public double getHeight(){
    return  this.heigth;
}

public void setLength( double theLength ){
    if ( theLength <= 0 )
        return;
    this.length = theLength;
}

public void setHeight( double theHeight ){
    if (theHeight <= 0 )
        return;
    this.heigth = theHeight;

}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s: \n%s: %s (%s) \n%s: %d \n%s: $%,.2f",
                      "Rect Surface Area ", "Rect Peremeter", getSurfaceArea(), getPeremeter());
}

 public double getSizeAmount(){

}

   }
```

**circle class:**

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
private double radius;

public Circle( double theRadius ){
    super( "Circle" );
    if ( theRadius <= 0.0 )
        setRadius( Shape.DEFAULT_SIZE );
    else
        setRadius( theRadius );
}

public Circle(String string, String string2, String string3, String string4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public double getSurfaceArea(){

    return this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI;
}

public double getPeremeter(){
    ;
    return 2 * this.radius + Math.PI;
}

public double getRadius(){
    return this.radius;

}

public void setRadius( double theRadius ) {
    if( theRadius <= 0 )
        return;
    this.radius = theRadius;
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;

     public double getSizeAmount(){

     }

     public String toString(){
         return String.format("%s: \n%s: %s (%s) \n%s: %d \n%s: $%,.2f",
                  "Circle Surface Area ", "Circle Peremeter", getSurfaceArea(), getPeremeter());
     }
}
   }
```

**triangle class:**

```
//triangle interface decleration
public interface Triangle {



double getSizeAmount(); //calculate sizes of triangle; no implementation

    }//end interface triangle
```

**main class:**

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;




    public class ShapeApp {

//public static void main(String args[])
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Triangle triangleObjects[] = new Triangle[ 4 ];

    triangleObjects[ 0 ] = new Rectangle("3.5", "4.6","42");
    triangleObjects[ 1 ] = new Rectangle("3", "2","34");
    triangleObjects[ 2 ] = new Circle("Circle", "Rectangle","0808","0808");
    triangleObjects[ 3 ] = new Circle("Circle","Rectangle","2334","2423");

    System.out.println( "List of all Shapes:\n" );

    for( Triangle currentTriangle : triangleObjects ){

        System.out.printf("%s \n%s: $%,.2f\n\n",
                currentTriangle.toString(),
                "ovo testiramo", currentTriangle.getSizeAmount());

    }


}

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor Rectangle(String, String, String) is undefined
The constructor Rectangle(String, String, String) is undefined

at ShapeApp.main(ShapeApp.java:14)
```

Comment: How could you have got that much code before becoming confused by that (relatively straightforward) error?  Is this as much of your homework as your study buddy would give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message is very clear:

```
The constructor Rectangle(String, String, String) is undefined

at ShapeApp.main(ShapeApp.java:14)
```

You are creating Rectangle object with 3 parameters.

```
 new Rectangle("3.5", "4.6","42");
```

But your Rectangle class has only two constructors

> 1) Consturctor with Zero args  2) Constructor with 2 args

```
public Rectangle() {
  ......

}

public Rectangle(double theLength, double theHeight )
{ ....
}
```

You need to add constructor with 3 arguments in `Rectangle` class (or) Change your object creation to two args constructor.

Comment: thanks man! sorry ive been coding this all day, my brain cant function anymore